# standard c library for escaping a string

Tags: c, string, escaping

Is there a standard C library function to escape C-strings?

For example, if I had the C string:

```
char example[] = "first line\nsecond line: \"inner quotes\"";
```

And I wanted to print

```
"first line\nsecond line: \"inner quotes\""
```

Is there a library function that will do that transformation for me?  Rolling my own just seems a little silly.

Bonus points if I can give it a length to escape (so it stops before or beyond the `\0`).

Comment: Stopping beyond the `\0` seems dangerous, you better be 100% sure that the length is valid or chaos will ensue.

Comment: useful though when I want to display some binary data semi-safely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were writing GPL stuff you might use http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/quotearg.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: marking this as accepted because it suggested a library function (even if not in the standard load), and didn't roll its own (which really wasn't what I was asking for).

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard C library function for this.

When you use the declaration

```
char example[] = "first line\nsecond line: \"inner quotes\"";
```

the escape sequences will be interpreted and replaced by the compiler.  You will have to "un-interpret" the characters that C escapes.  Here's a quick-n-dirty example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void print_unescaped(char* ptr, int len) {
    if (!ptr) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++, ptr++) {
        switch (*ptr) {
            case '\0': printf("\\0");  break;
            case '\a': printf("\\a");  break;
            case '\b': printf("\\b");  break;
            case '\f': printf("\\f");  break;
            case '\n': printf("\\n");  break;
            case '\r': printf("\\r");  break;
            case '\t': printf("\\t");  break;
            case '\v': printf("\\v");  break;
            case '\\': printf("\\\\"); break;
            case '\?': printf("\\\?"); break;
            case '\'': printf("\\\'"); break;
            case '\"': printf("\\\""); break;
            default:
                if (isprint(*ptr)) printf("%c",     *ptr);
                else               printf("\\%03o", *ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but `puts` appends a trailing newline.

Comment: what the hell is `else` for a `switch`?

Comment: Ha! That takes me back to VB days with `Select Case` and `Case Else`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Good point, I should have noted that in my answer.  I used `gets` because it was cleaner to read than two `putchar` calls (given the space provided) and since I was trying to communicate the concept more than the implementation.  I will edit my answer to clarify this.  @Michael Krelin: It's latin for 'default', I translated it back though.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

You just mentioned that you wanted to print the string.

```
char example[] = "first line\nsecond line: \"inner quotes\"";
size_t length = strlen(example);
size_t i;

static const char *simple = "\\\'\"";
static const char *complex = "\a\b\f\n\r\t\v";
static const char *complexMap = "abfnrtv";

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    char *p;
    if (strchr(simple, example[i]))
    {
        putchar('\\');
        putchar(example[i]);
    }
    else if ((p = strchr(complex, example[i]))
    {
        size_t idx = p - complex;
        putchar('\\');
        putchar(complexMap[idx]);
    }
    else if (isprint(example[i]))
    {
        putchar(example[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\\%03o", example[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about other nonprintables? \033, for instance?

Comment: @Michael Krelin: Untested, but now prints unprintables as octal escapes.

Comment: You get my vote as the first and only who actually took are of the issue ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't \e fit better than \033?

Comment: @u_Ltd. `\e` is not a standard escape sequence in C. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>    
/* int c_quote(const char* src, char* dest, int maxlen)
 *
 * Quotes the string given so that it will be parseable by a c compiler.
 * Return the number of chars copied to the resulting string (including any nulls)
 *
 * if dest is NULL, no copying is performed, but the number of chars required to 
 * copy will be returned.
 *
 * maxlen characters are copied. If maxlen is negative, 
 * strlen is used to find the length of the source string, and the whole string
 * including the NULL-terminator is copied.
 *
 * Note that this function will not null-terminate the string in dest.
 * If the string in src is not null-terminated, or maxlen is specified to not
 * include the whole src, remember to null-terminate dest afterwards.
 *
 */
int c_quote(const char* src, char* dest, int maxlen) {
    int count = 0;
    if(maxlen < 0) {
        maxlen = strlen(src)+1;      /* add 1 for NULL-terminator */
    }

    while(src  && maxlen > 0) {
        switch(*src) {

            /* these normal, printable chars just need a slash appended */
            case '\\':
            case '\"':
            case '\'':
                if(dest) {
                    *dest++ = '\\';
                    *dest++ = *src;
                }
                count += 2;
                break; 

            /* newlines/tabs and unprintable characters need a special code.
             * Use the macro CASE_CHAR defined below.
             * The first arg for the macro is the char to compare to,
             * the 2nd arg is the char to put in the result string, after the '\' */
#define CASE_CHAR(c, d) case c:\
    if(dest) {\
        *dest++ = '\\'; *dest++ = (d);\
        }\
count += 2;\
break;
            /* --------------  */
            CASE_CHAR('\n', 'n');
            CASE_CHAR('\t', 't');
            CASE_CHAR('\b', 'b');
            /*  ------------- */

#undef CASE_CHAR


            /* by default, just copy the char over */
            default:
                if(dest) {
                    *dest++ = *src;
                }
                count++;
        }

        ++src;
        --maxlen;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No standard C function, but not too hard to roll your own

nothing too pretty  but :-

```
void escape_str(char *dest, char *src)
{
     *dest = 0;
     while(*src)
     {
         switch(*src)
         {
             case '\n' : strcat(dest++, "\\n"); break;
             case '\"' : strcat(dest++, "\\\""); break;
             default:  *dest = *src;
         }
         *src++;
         *dest++;
         *dest = 0;                     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I felt like my previous answer was cheating because a function that writes to a buffer is much more useful than one that simply writes to `stdout`, so here's an alternative solution which works out how much memory one needs if `dst` is `NULL`, and also stops at `dstLen` as per the requirement.

It's probably a little inefficient with all the `if(dst)` checking.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t str_escape(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstLen)
{
    const char complexCharMap[] = "abtnvfr";

    size_t i;
    size_t srcLen = strlen(src);    
    size_t dstIdx = 0;

    // If caller wants to determine required length (supplying NULL for dst)
    // then we set dstLen to SIZE_MAX and pretend the buffer is the largest
    // possible, but we never write to it. Caller can also provide dstLen
    // as 0 if no limit is wanted.
    if (dst == NULL || dstLen == 0) dstLen = SIZE_MAX;

    for (i = 0; i < srcLen && dstIdx < dstLen; i++)
    {
        size_t complexIdx = 0;

        switch (src[i])
        {
            case '\'':
            case '\"':
            case '\\':
                if (dst && dstIdx <= dstLen - 2)
                {
                    dst[dstIdx++] = '\\';
                    dst[dstIdx++] = src[i];
                }
                else dstIdx += 2;
                break;

            case '\r': complexIdx++;
            case '\f': complexIdx++;
            case '\v': complexIdx++;
            case '\n': complexIdx++;
            case '\t': complexIdx++;
            case '\b': complexIdx++;
            case '\a':
                if (dst && dstIdx <= dstLen - 2)
                {
                    dst[dstIdx++] = '\\';
                    dst[dstIdx++] = complexCharMap[complexIdx];
                }
                else dstIdx += 2;
                break;

            default:
                if (isprint(src[i]))
                {
                    // simply copy the character
                    if (dst)
                        dst[dstIdx++] = src[i];
                    else
                        dstIdx++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // produce octal escape sequence
                    if (dst && dstIdx <= dstLen - 4)
                    {
                        dst[dstIdx++] = '\\';
                        dst[dstIdx++] = ((src[i] & 0300) >> 6) + '0';
                        dst[dstIdx++] = ((src[i] & 0070) >> 3) + '0';
                        dst[dstIdx++] = ((src[i] & 0007) >> 0) + '0';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dstIdx += 4;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    if (dst && dstIdx <= dstLen)
        dst[dstIdx] = '\0';

    return dstIdx;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
while(*src++)
{
  if(*src == '\\' || *src == '\"' || *src == '\'')
    *dest++ = '\\';

  *dest++ = *src++;
}
```

Comment: this code lacks \r\n\f\a\b\t and other nonprintables handling

Comment: don't forget leading and trailing double quotes, checking `isprint()` and producing appropriate escapes for common non-printables and whitespace (`\n`, `\t`) and octal escapes for others (`\0`, `\377`).

Comment: that won't work as the escape characters don't actually make it into the string

Comment: Pavel, how is it not true? consider the "\r\033\n" string, what will become of it? (but the downvote is not mine)

Comment: @Michael: what will become of it is this: "\\r\\033\\n" which is exactly what is needed.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the string, consisting of carriage return, escape and line feed, not backslash r, backslash zero three three and backslash n.