# C "backslash encode/decode" special characters like quote, tab, escape, newline, etc

Tags: c, printf, terminology, encode, backslash

I would like to take a string like "Bob[TAB]John[TAB]Harry "The Hammer" Jones" and "backslash" encode the string as such:

"Bob\tJohn\tHarry \"The Hammer\" Jones"

So I can read/write single line quoted values to file without the usual suspects like ESC, TAB, newline messing it up but still stored in the string.

a) Is there a "standard" way to do this instead or re-inventing the wheel?
b) What "word" am I looking for that describes what I want to do?  I feel like this should certainly be a "dup" but I don't know the right term if this is the case.  For a URL, this would be URLEncode/Decode, but what is the word for "backslash encode special characters in C"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725385/standard-c-library-for-escaping-a-string

Comment: There's really no nice way to do this, besides going through the string and manually translate the special characters.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be looking for an equivalent of `JSON.stringify` specificly for C strings.

Comment: Yeah, "stringify" equilivalent sounds about right.  That other thread provides a couple of ideas, but seems clear "roll your own" is more or less what I'll need to do.  Thanks all.

Comment: This question is a dup and should be closed.  If that is something I should do myself, I'm not sure how to do it.