# Escaping a char * in C

Tags: c, string, stringification

I had to made something for a little programm some days ago, I needed to turn a string like `"foo\n"` into its stringified form (something like `"\"foo\\n\""`).

But I found nothing, so I ended up writing my own function (and it worked fine). But I'm still wondering : Is there a function to stringify strings like this?

I know the python equivalent `"%r" % strtostringify`, and I know that I can strinfifying pieces of code at compiling with preprocessor directives :

```
#define TOSTRING(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) TOSTRING(X)
```

but is there a way to make it dynamically in `C`?

Comment: The process you're describing is normally called "escaping"  , and there's no built-in escaping function in C (nor in the preprocessor).  "stringify" means to change `X` into `"X"`, where `X` is a pre-processing token (not an arbitrary sequence of bytes)

Comment: @M.M Actually, the `gcc` documentation's refers to the `#` use in preprocessor directives as "stringizing" (perhaps both words are used?), but thank you for making it clear that there is no such thing in C standard library. :)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

Comment: @AppWriter Done, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: yes, the `#` operator is for stringizing as I described in my comment (not escaping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping special characters is not provided in any standard [c](/questions/tagged/c) function.

---

For GPL, you can take a look in [standard c library for escaping a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725385/standard-c-library-for-escaping-a-string).

Comment: That's all I needed to know. :) Thank you for this answer and for the link.